SwiftUI dropDestination(for: URL.self) working on macOS but not iOS
I have the following view that works perfectly fine on macOS:
public struct DropView: View {
    
    @Bindable var store: StoreOf<Feature>
    @State var isDropTargeted = false
    
    public init(
        store: StoreOf<Feature>
    ) {
        self.store = store
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        Group {
            if isDropTargeted && store.dropsAccepted {
                ZStack {
                    Color.accentColor.opacity(0.2)
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "arrow.up.document")
                            .symbolRenderingMode(.hierarchical)
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 64, height: 64)
                        Text("Add file")
                            .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Color.clear
            }
        }
        .dropDestination(for: URL.self) { urls, _ in
            store.send(.filesDropped(urls))
            return store.dropsAccepted
        } isTargeted: { targeted in
            isDropTargeted = targeted
        }
    }
}

It does not work on iOS or iPadOS though, neither in the simulator nor on a real device. (I made sure that dropsAccepted is true.)
I've tried different things, none of which succeeded:

Replacing the clear color with a blue one doesn't make a difference.
Neither does using onDrop instead.
A contentShape(Rectangle()) prevents me from interacting with the underlying view but doesn't change anything regarding the dropping.
Adding the .dropDestination to the color (blue or clear, with or without contentShape) doesn't help either.

When the color is blue instead of clear the dragged file representation gets a "forbidden" icon when it is dragged over the view. Nothing else changes. Dropping isn't possible and isDropTargeted isn't set to true either.
Does anyone have an idea about what could be going on here?

Edit: Not sure if this is related but I just added .draggable(url) to another view in the same app. On the Mac I can drag an image out. On iOS nothing happens.

An arbitrary file from the Files app. I've tried text files, images and also a folder. On the Mac I can drop any of these items from the Finder.
Not sure if this is related but I just added .draggable(url) to another view in the same app. On the Mac I can drag an image out. On iOS nothing happens.

So if it's file URLs it should work, right? I tried a different color but it didn't change anything.

I'm dragging a file. I put my finger over an image, a text file or a folder in the Files app, long press, move the finger over the drop destination and lift the finger. Drag and drop is more convenient on macOS than using a selection dialog and I just want to have the behavior work cross-platform as that's what SwiftUI promises.

Well you need to make some compromises. Instead of getting the URLs of the files, which iOS will not give you without a fileImporter, how about getting its contents as Data and copy it to a location you control? And I don't think SwiftUI ever promised to have the exact same behaviour across platforms. Having platform-specific things is inevitable.

You can totally just not show the fileImporter on macOS. It's easy enough to do with some #ifs.

Oh I think I made a typo in one of my previous comments. I meant to say that files from the Files app are not URLs on iOS.

Maybe that's it. I tried it with for: Data.self and now I get the files once I change the color to something that's not clear.

So it is possible to get URLs, but only via a Transferable item. I posted what I found as an answer.

Seems like Sweeper was on the right track.
The Files app on iOS seems not to to provide URLs.
In order to get them I needed to create a Transferable item with a FileRepresentation:
struct TransferItem: Transferable, Equatable, Sendable {
    
    public var url: URL
    
    static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        FileRepresentation(contentType: .item) { item in
            SentTransferredFile(item.url)
        } importing: { received in
            @Dependency(\.fileClient) var fileClient
            let temporaryFolder = fileClient.temporaryReplacementDirectory(received.file)
            let temporaryURL = temporaryFolder.appendingPathComponent(received.file.lastPathComponent)
            let url = try fileClient.copyItemToUniqueURL(at: received.file, to: temporaryURL)
            return Self(url)
        }
    }
}

And then use it like this:
.dropDestination(for: TransferItem.self) { items, _ in
    let urls = items.map(\.url)
        store.send(.filesDropped(urls))
        return store.dropsAccepted
    } isTargeted: { targeted in
        isDropTargeted = targeted
    }


Yeah this is what I had in mind too, if you are fine with not having the "real" URL of the file.

Yeah, I'm fine with that. I just need a URL in order to import the file in the current format and with the current filename. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!
